# C# date time format

Tags: c#

How to get date time in

> 2017-06-15T14:20:30+02:00

format from

```
DateTime.utc.now
```

It is an ISO 8601 date format. I tried with

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss") + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString(@"zzz");
```

But the date I am getting is

> 2017-10-20-T09:29:20+00:00

The application is hosted in Azure.

Comment: Application is hosted in azure.

Comment: Expected format is the same as output format... only date and time itself is different... what is the problem? `2017-06-15T14:20:30+02:00` and `2017-10-20-T09:29:20+00:00` is the same format....

Comment: EpicKip is right, your desired format and actual reported format are the same. Are you asking how to get the date in a different timezone, rather than a different format?

Comment: @zzz always returns 00:00 value. Not sure is it because of time zone. If yes then how to resolve that. Sorry about 'Format' word as it is creating confusion.

Comment: Azure always runs in the UTC timezone, not a local (to what?) timezone

Comment: It is not clear what the expected output should be.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding ISO8601. For `UtcNow`, the offset suffix will always be +00:00. The format shows local time, and the suffix means how much the local time is offset relatively to UTC time.

`UtcNow` is the current time in the UTC zone, not the local zone - ergo, its offset to UTC is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") + DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.ToString();
```

This is how this works:

EX 1:

```
DateTimeOffset localTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset utcTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

Console.WriteLine("Local Time:          {0}", localTime.ToString("T"));
Console.WriteLine("Difference from UTC: {0}", localTime.Offset.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("UTC:                 {0}", utcTime.ToString("T"));
// If run on a particular date at 1:19 PM, the example produces
// the following output:
//    Local Time:          1:19:43 PM
//    Difference from UTC: -07:00:00
//    UTC:                 8:19:43 PM
```

Ex 2:

```
var dt = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        string s = dt.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss \"GMT\"zzz");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: I need to use Utc.now instead of dt you mentioned so should I proceed like this.  Datetime.utcnow.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss \"GMT\"zzz");

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
    DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:sszzz")
```

Comment: same result no luck.